# Is it true that every finite subset of a Hausdorff space has no limit point?

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space. Assume a finite $A\subset X$ has a limit point $b$, say. Every pair $a\in A, b\in X$ has disjoint neighborhoods. Denote those neighborhoods of $b$ by $U_a$ for each $a\in A$. Now, $\cap U_a$ is clearly a neighborhood of $b$ and disjoint from $A$, contradicting the fact that $b$ is a limit point of $A$. So I think the answer is yes, if I didn't make any mistakes.

Comment: You’ve shown correctly that $A$ has no limit point in $X\setminus A$. To finish the argument, you need to show that no point $a\in A$ is a limit point of $A$, but this is basically the same argument applied to $A\setminus\{a\}$.

Comment: Your solution is mostly correct. I think you can improve it by avoiding contradiction, though. If you assume $b\in X$, use your argument to show that $b$ isn't a limit point since you can find an open set around it that doesn't contain any point of $A$ distinct from itself.

Comment: @Clayton: It **is** correct, as far as it goes; it’s just (slightly) incomplete. Whether avoiding contradiction is an improvement is strictly a matter of taste.

Comment: The way you proved that each point in $X-A$ is not a limit point of $A$ can even be generalized in order to show that each point in $X-A$ has a neighborhood disjoint from a neighborhood of $A$ is $A$ is compact. But then you have to consider also a neighborhood of $a$ each time, not only for $b$.